# I want to randomize my question list in different page

Tags: android, kotlin

i want to randomize my question list:

```
object Constants{

    const val USER_NAME: String = "user_name"
    const val TOTAL_QUESTIONS: String = "total_question"
    const val CORRECT_ANSWER: String = "correct_answer"

    fun getQuestion(): ArrayList<Question> {
        val questionList = ArrayList<Question>()


        val que1 = Question(
         1,  "Destruídas pela chegada dos europeus, em que continente existiram as civilizações pré-colombianas?",
        2, "Ásia","América","África","Oceânia", 2
        )

        questionList.add(que1)

        val que2 = Question(
            2, "Qual é a capital da Tailândia?", 3, "Bangkok","Manila","Pattaya","Phuket", 1
        )

         questionList.add(que2)

        val que3 = Question(
          3,  "Qual destes países europeus não faz fronteira com nenhum dos restantes?", 1,
            "Bélgica","Holanda","Polónia","França", 3
        )

        questionList.add(que3)

        val que4=Question(
            4,"Qual naipe do baralho tem desenho de um coração?", 5,
            "Ouros","Paus","Copas","Espadas", 3
        )

        questionList.add(que4)

        val que5=Question(
            5, "Quem desenhou o Elevador de Santa Justa em Lisboa?", 8,
            "Gustave Eiffel","Mesnier de Ponsard","Frank Lloyd Wright","Charles Rennie Mackintosh",
        2
        )

        questionList.add(que5)

        val que6=Question(6, "O kitesurf é...", 1,
            "Uma ave","Uma cidade","Um desporto","Uma dança", 3


        )

        questionList.add(que6)

        val que7 = Question(
            7,"O que podemos encontrar dentro de uma ostra?",2,
            "Um caroço","Uma pérola","Um diamante","Um amendoim",2
        )

        questionList.add(que7)


        val que8=Question(
            8,"Qual é o primeiro nome de Shakespeare?", 3,
            "Wilfred","Winston","Wayne","William",4
        )

        questionList.add(que8)

        val que9=Question(
            9,"Em 1987, os Xutos e Pontapés lançaram o seu terceiro álbum. Chama-se 'Circo de...'",5,
            "Acrobatas","Bestas","Leões","Feras",4
        )

        questionList.add(que9)

        val que10 = Question(
           10, "Complete o provérbio: 'Dezembro frio, calor no...'", 3,
            "Domicílio","Aconchego","Abrigo","Estio",4
        )

        questionList.add(que10)

        val que11 = Question(
            11, "Qual a capital de Inglaterra?",
             1,
            "Londres","Madrid","Lisboa","Tóquio", 1
        )


    questionList.add(que11)

        val que12 = Question(
            12, "Qual a capital do México?",
            1, "Atenas", "Brasilia", "Nova Deli", "Cidade do México", 4
        )

        questionList.add(que12)

        val que13 = Question(
            13, "Qual é o melhor amigo do homem?", 2,
            "Gato","Veado","Cão","Gorila", 3
        )
        questionList.add(que13)

        val que14 = Question(
            14, "Que valor obtemos se multiplicarmos 0,1 por 5,1?", 3,
            "5","0,51","51","510",2
        )

        questionList.add(que14)

        val que15 = Question(
            15,"Como se chama a orquestra barroca sediada em Lisboa e com direção artística de Massimo Mazzeo?",15,
            "Divino Sospiro", "Ava Inferi", "Cacophony", "Vozes da Rádio",1
        )

        questionList.add(que15)

        return questionList
    }
```

and in my opinion the best to do it is when i press start it randomize the `questionList` and start the program but if not tell me the best way to do it or other suggestions its for a quiz game order of the Question class' constructor: the first number is the id of the question, question, level of the question, answer and then correct answer

Comment: welcome to SO. please don't use android studio if you're not asking about the IDE, rather use the android tag

Answer (score -1):

You can use `shuffle` to achieve what you want.

For more information: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/shuffle.html

Also, you may use `mutableListOf` to create your first list, instead of adding creating an empty one and adding items one by one.

Answer (score -1):

### Kotlin code

1. Read the CSV file.
2. Ignore the first line with headers.
3. Map to string array handling quotes correctly with regex.
4. Map to a data class.
5. Finally shuffle list.

```kotlin
data class Question(
    val id: Int,
    val question: String,
    val difficulty: Int,
    val answerIndex: Int,
    val answers: List<String>
)

fun displayQuestion(q: Question) = println("" +
        "Question: ${q.question}\n" +
        "Possible answers:\n" +
        q.answers.mapIndexed { i, s ->" ${i+1} - $s"}.joinToString("\n")
)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val questions = File("questions.csv")
        .useLines { it.toList() }
        .filterIndexed { i, _ -> i != 0 }
        .map { it.split(",(?=(?:[^\\\"]*\\\"[^\\\"]*\\\")*[^\\\"]*\$)".toRegex()) }
        .map { Question(it[0].toInt(), it[1], it[2].toInt(), it[3].toInt(), it.drop(4)) }
        .shuffled()

    displayQuestion(questions[0])

    print("What is the correct answer (number): ")
    val result = (questions[0].answerIndex ==  readLine()?.toInt())

    val resultString = if(result) "Correct" else "Wrong"
    println("You got the answer: $resultString")
}
```

### Result

```
Question: Quem desenhou o Elevador de Santa Justa em Lisboa?
Possible answers:
 1 - Gustave Eiffel
 2 - Mesnier de Ponsard
 3 - Frank Lloyd Wright
 4 - Charles Rennie Mackintosh
What is the correct answer (number): 2
You got the answer: Correct
```

### File structure

```
project/
|
├── src/
|    └── main.kt
└── question.csv
```

### Table

Use a spreadsheet program to write down your questions in a more user friendly enviroment.
Export it as a .csv file. Here is a link to a version on [Google sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F04B48Ct53YOxDmfMEPAB22GQM-rjJlotYYFaG3q3po/edit?usp=sharing).

| Id | Question | Difficulty | Correct answer | Answer 1 | Answer 2 | Answer 3 | Answer 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Destruídas pela chegada dos europeus em que continente existiram as civilizações pré-colombianas? | 2 | 2 | Ásia | América | África | Oceânia |
| 2 | Qual é a capital da Tailândia? | 3 | 1 | Bangkok | Manila | Pattaya | Phuket |
| 3 | Qual destes países europeus não faz fronteira com nenhum dos restantes? | 1 | 3 | Bélgica | Holanda | Polónia | França |
| 4 | Qual naipe do baralho tem desenho de um coração? | 5 | 3 | Ouros | Paus | Copas | Espadas |
| 5 | Quem desenhou o Elevador de Santa Justa em Lisboa? | 8 | 2 | Gustave Eiffel | Mesnier de Ponsard | Frank Lloyd Wright | Charles Rennie Mackintosh |
| 6 | O kitesurf é... | 1 | 3 | Uma ave | Uma cidade | Um desporto | Uma dança |
| 7 | O que podemos encontrar dentro de uma ostra? | 2 | 2 | Um caroço | Uma pérola | Um diamante | Um amendoim |
| 8 | Qual é o primeiro nome de Shakespeare? | 3 | 4 | Wilfred | Winston | Wayne | William |
| 9 | Em 1987 os Xutos e Pontapés lançaram o seu terceiro álbum. Chama-se 'Circo de...' | 5 | 4 | Acrobatas | Bestas | Leões | Feras |
| 10 | Complete o provérbio: 'Dezembro frio, calor no...' | 3 | 4 | Domicílio | Aconchego | Abrigo | Estio |
| 11 | Qual a capital de Inglaterra? | 1 | 1 | Londres | Madrid | Lisboa | Tóquio |
| 12 | Qual a capital do México? | 1 | 4 | Atenas | Brasilia | Nova Deli | Cidade do México |
| 13 | Qual é o melhor amigo do homem? | 2 | 3 | Gato | Veado | Cão | Gorila |
| 14 | Que valor obtemos se multiplicarmos 0,1 por 5,1? | 5 | 2 | 0 | 51 | 51 | 510 |
| 15 | Como se chama a orquestra barroca sediada em Lisboa e com direção artística de Massimo Mazzeo? | 15 | 1 | Divino Sospiro | Ava Inferi | Cacophony | Vozes da Rádio |

Comment: And can i delete the page where i have the questions? and insert there in file all the questions i want?

Comment: @NunoCADSE Yes put all the question in the question.csv file

Comment: And i how i import the question.csv to the appear in the screen

Comment: And i delete the page where i have the questions and put all in question.csv but how i can put them to display in correct screen in my case QuizQuestionActivity

Comment: https://pastecord.com/ebesitujux

I use this code to display the questions how do i swap to the google sheet